# ThreeJS How to move the center coordination of the scene?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to move the center of the scene from the center X of the mesh to the lowest x point (floor intersection) ? as I need to inspect intersection point according to the center (0,0,0) using Raycaster ?

[image]

Comment: why cant move your object higher?

Comment: How can I get the height of the mesh so I can calculate the required height to move it up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `geometry.boundingBox` is undefined then you can compute it by

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox ()
```

which updates the `geometry.boundingBox` attribute.

Then you can use `geometry.boundingBox.min` and `geometry.boundingBox.max` to figure out how much to move your model.